# Setting File Name in FileDialog

Tags: java, filedialog

Is it possible set the text of the "Save As: "  line in a `FileDialog`? I would like to set it so that when the dialog is created, there is a suggested name for the file instead of just blank space (as shown below). Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that like .

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 if (targetFile != null) {
 chooser.setSelectedFile(targetFile);
 } else {
 chooser.setSelectedFile(newFile("default.xyz"));
 }
 int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
 if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
 targetFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
 }
```

That pops up a Save file dialog in the working directory and dispalys default.xyz